# Boost connected components not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I'm having trouble getting boost's connected components algorithm working reliably. I want to use it to separate collections of 3D point data. I have a data set where there is are two obvious 'clusters' of 3D points separated by a large distance.

I create an undirected Boost graph object with bundled information which is a simple 'point' class, this contains an x, y and z property and a method to calculate distance of this point from another.

```
adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS,Point> Graph;
```

I have a vector of point information (Point_dat) which I now transfer to vertices of the graph

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < Inter_dat.size(); i++)
    {
        // Create a new vertex for every element of the original data
        add_vertex(Graph);
        (Graph)[i] = Point_dat[i];          
    }
```

I now iterate through the vertices of the graph (in two loops) to calculate the distance from each vertex to each other vertex (I know there are more efficient ways of doing this but this is a first stab)
If the distance between two points is below a threshold, I add an edge between the two vertices.

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, Point>::vertex_iterator iterator;
std::pair<iterator, iterator> p = vertices(Graph);
    for (iterator it = p.first; it != p.second; it++)
    {
        for (iterator it2 = it; it2 != p.second; it2++)
        {               
            double thisdist = Graph[*it].Distance(Graph[*it2]);
            if (thisdist < distance_thresh & thisdist > 0)
            {
                add_edge(*it,*it2, Graph);                  
            }
        }
    }
```

I then calculate the connected components.

```
    std::vector<int> comp(num_vertices(Graph));
    int num = connected_components(Graph, &comp[0]);
```

The problem is, the data isn't being separated into the two clusters. The main cluster still contains some of the second. In fact if I re-run the analysis using the largest component (as selected by Boost) it finds a number of new components.

Why isn't it working? Do I need to add different parameters?

UPDATE: To give more context, I'm trying to implement a process I developed in Matlab in C++. To try and see the root of the problem I saved the edges of my graph

```
std::ofstream myfile("D:\\edges.txt");
    auto q = edges(Graph);
    for (auto it = q.first; it != q.second; ++it)
        myfile << *it << std::endl;
    myfile.close();
```

and imported the resulting data into Matlab. I then used Matlab's connected components process on this edge information and it gave me exactly the right answer. It seems that I'm setting the graph up correctly but Boosts connected components isn't giving me the right answer.

Comment: How do you assess that components given by boost are different? There is also a bug when you create the graph it should be `thisdist < distance_thresh && thisdist > 0`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, will change code.
In Boost, there are 3 components: (1) contains 938 points (2) contains 2 (3) contains 56
In matlab there are 3 components: (1) contains 920 points (2) contains 2 (3) contains 74
When I view the points in each component (in meshlab or matlab) I can see that Boost has not separated them correctly

Comment: can you share the input data? It's hard to tell what results you are getting and whether your expectations are correct

Comment: No problem, you can download the sample .xyz file from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1584218/test.xyz). I set all the z components to zero in order to 'flatten' the data and create two distinct groups. Data is in ASCII with header row and comma separated

Comment: In case you're available: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a useful threshold. I did some statistical analys: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea39d47bd845d9c3)**

Comment: That's great, I can learn a lot from that, thanks a lot.
Apologies I didn't mention that I used a distance threshold of 15, which works fine in Matlab. Viewing the data in Meshlab (or equivalent) it's easy to see a large gap between collections of points. Not sure what that means about the Boost connected components and how to get it working?